# Converting code from TFLearn to work in Keras

Tags: python, keras, tflearn

I am using some code written in TFLearn as a reference and trying to re-write it using Keras. I'm fairly new to both packages and I am not sure if I have written it properly.

I have tried my code - and it works - but I'm not getting the expected result (the accuracy doesn't improve over 20+ epochs) and I am wondering if I have made a mistake somewhere.

In terms of my data, I have a 'data' directory which has 'train' and 'validation' directories. Inside of each of those are 3 directories for each of my 3 image classes.

Original TFLearn code:

```
import numpy as np
import tflearn
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression

def createModel(nbClasses,imageSize):

    convnet = input_data(shape=[None, imageSize, imageSize, 1], name='input')

    convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 64, 2, activation='elu', weights_init="Xavier")
    convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 2)

    convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 128, 2, activation='elu', weights_init="Xavier")
    convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 2)

    convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 256, 2, activation='elu', weights_init="Xavier")
    convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 2)

    convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 512, 2, activation='elu', weights_init="Xavier")
    convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 2)

    convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 1024, activation='elu')
    convnet = dropout(convnet, 0.5)

    convnet = fully_connected(convnet, nbClasses, activation='softmax')
    convnet = regression(convnet, optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy')

    model = tflearn.DNN(convnet)
return model
```

My code using Keras:

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers.core import Flatten, Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.optimizers import rmsprop
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, ZeroPadding2D
import numpy as np

num_classes = 3
image_size = 256
nb_epoch = 80
batch_size = 32
nb_train_samples = 7994
nb_validation_samples = 2000

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, image_size, image_size)
else:
    input_shape = (image_size, image_size, 3)

model = Sequential()

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1), input_shape=input_shape))

model.add(Conv2D(64, 2, activation='elu', kernel_initializer='glorot_normal'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128, 2, activation='elu', kernel_initializer='glorot_normal'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(256, 2, activation='elu', kernel_initializer='glorot_normal'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(512, 2, activation='elu', kernel_initializer='glorot_normal'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024))
model.add(Activation('elu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
opt = rmsprop()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
         optimizer = opt,
         metrics = ['accuracy'])

train_data_dir = 'data/train'
validation_data_dir = 'data/validation'
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale= 1./255)
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(image_size, image_size),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical'
    )

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(image_size, image_size),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical'
    )



model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                steps_per_epoch=(nb_train_samples // batch_size),
                epochs=nb_epoch,
                validation_data=validation_generator,
                validation_steps=(nb_validation_samples // batch_size)
               )

model.save_weights('first_try.h5')
```

Comment: How do you batch your data and how do you train? Could you add your code for that?

Comment: Just added the rest of my code

Comment: I tried your code with three classes of the MNIST dataset and could train just fine. Accuracy increases over the first epochs as expected. At least for MNIST I could train much faster by using only the first two Conv layers and a Dense Layer of 64. Depending on your data I suggest you try with a simpler model (i.e. 2 Conv layers), check if the model is learning and then improve from there.

Comment: Thanks for checking my code. I'm using this code to classify between 3 music genres using 256x256 spectrograms, but the accuracy is always around 0.33 (no better than random). The TFlearn code is from https://github.com/despoisj/DeepAudioClassification who attempted a similar project, apparently with success. I'm not sure why I cannot replicate the same

Comment: UPDATE: I did as you suggested and took it back to just 2 conv layers and val_acc has steadily risen from an initial 0.3571 to 0.6417 after 8 epochs. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code with three classes of the MNIST dataset and could train just fine. Accuracy increases over the first epochs as expected.

At least for MNIST I could train much faster by using only the first two Conv layers and a Dense Layer of 64. Depending on your data I suggest you try with a simpler model (i.e. 2 Conv layers), check if the model is learning and then improve from there.